# Is there a way to record the value of an index when a listener is being created, so that that same value is used when the listener function is called?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When an event listener function is called, the value of the index is no longer the same value as when the listener was created

I'm creating all the markers and their listeners through iteration. however when 'infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);' is called after the iteration, 'i' has a different value and opens a different marker's infowindow. How can I make this point to the marker being clicked?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function(){
  infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
}
```

I can see why this is happening but I'm not sure how to get around it. 'infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);' is not called until the marker is clicked, and by that stage i has a different value.

Comment: Please post more code - is your `i` created with `for (var i = 0; ... i++)` or something very similar?

Comment: Due to your lack of response I'm going to assume that it is

Comment: Yes it is created with   for (var i = 0; ... i++)

Comment: CertainPerformance, do you happen to have a link to where this question was answered previously? I haven't been able to find one

Comment: Try looking at the top of this page.

Comment: Oh cheers, sorry I'm not very familiar with SO

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the **i** value is modified when the callback is called

Try bellow snippet

```
(function(local_i){
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[local_i], 'click', function(){
  infowindow.open(map, marker[local_i]);
})(i);
```

This is a classic issue in javascript that can be solved by understanding closures in javascript.

**EDIT:**
If you are writing ES6 javascript
and have a for loop enclosed outside that function call
you can also modify the snippet like that
because **let** initialises each time the loop runs

```
for(let i = 0; i < something.length; i++){    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function(){
      infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
    })
}
```